# Keras Model Multi Input - TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'input')

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build a CNN that receives multiple inputs and I am trying the following:

```
input = keras.Input()
classifier = keras.Model(inputs=input,output=classifier)
```

When run the code I am receiving the following error for line 6 though:

```
TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'input').
```

A hint would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Are you sure this is the code that produces the error? Which line triggers the error? I don't see any keyword argument called input here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some parameters of your code are not specified. I have copied your example with some numbers that you can change back.

```
import keras

input_dim_1 = 10
input1 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(input_dim_1,1))
cnn_classifier_1 = keras.layers.Conv1D(64, 5, activation='sigmoid')(input1)
cnn_classifier_1 = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(cnn_classifier_1)
cnn_classifier_1 = keras.layers.Conv1D(48, 5, activation='sigmoid')(cnn_classifier_1)
cnn_classifier_1 = keras.models.Model(inputs=input1,outputs=cnn_classifier_1)
```

Some things to note

1. The imports of your layers were not right. You need to import the layers/models you want from the right places. You can check my code against yours to see this.
2. With the functional API of `keras` you do not need to specify the input shape as you have done in the first `Conv1D` layer. This is handled automatically.
3. You need to correctly specify the keywords in `Model`. Specifically `inputs` and `outputs`. Different versions of `keras` use `input` / `output` or `inputs`/`outputs` as keywords for the call of the class `Model`.

Answer (score 2):

## Hey, its simple, use following code:

```
classifier = keras.Model(input, classifier)
```

instead of calling

```
classifier = keras.Model(inputs = input, output = classifier)
```

Issue seems to come from latest versions of `keras` implementation.